# ExtBase: cannot delete child object in scheduler task

Tags: typo3, parent-child, scheduler, extbase, removechild

I have following model: "Shelf" and "Book", being in 1:n relation.

There is also a scheduler task (extension "scheduler" 6.2.0) analysing books and deleting them. Scheduler task is divided into two classes: task itself and it's business logic.

Task:

```
namespace Vendor\MyExt\Scheduler;
class MultiStepProcessTask extends \TYPO3\CMS\Scheduler\Task\AbstractTask {
    public function execute() {
        $objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');

        $businessLogic = $objectManager->get(\Vendor\MyExt\Scheduler\MultiStepProcessTaskBusinessLogic::class);

        return $businessLogic->run();
    }
}
```

Business logic:

```
namespace Vendor\MyExt\Scheduler;
class MultiStepProcessTaskBusinessLogic {
    public function run() {
        $objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');

        $shelvesRepository = $objectManager->get('Vendor\\MyExt\\Domain\\Repository\\ShelvesRepository');
        $shelf = $shelvesRepository->findOneByLastFinishedTaskNumber(0);
        $book = $shelf->getBooks()->current();
        ....    
        $shelf->removeBook($book);
        $shelvesRepository->update($shelf);

        return 1;
    }
}
```

If called from my extension - everything is OK: the book is deleted.
To test it I put these lines into the list action of one controller:

```
$objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');
$businessLogic = $objectManager->get(\Vendor\MyExt\Scheduler\MultiStepProcessTaskBusinessLogic::class);
$businessLogic->run();
```

If called from scheduler (as task) the book is not deleted! Repository is created, shelf is fetched, book is fetched. But `$shelf->removeBook($book);` has no effect at all. Could someone please explain me why?

I'm using TYPO3 version 6.2.19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate the PersistenceManager and then call `PersistenceManager->persistAll();`. The reason for this is that within a controller action this is called by default at the end of every action as a kind of cleanup task. Your task wouldn't do this by default, so you need to persist manually.

Comment: Great! That was it. Thanks a lot.